# at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json, http-post

I am trying to upload a file using `HttpPost` and send it to `php` where I would get a response in `JsonArray`. However the problem I am having is to use the `JsonArray` or object to use in android app. The information from the array will then be put in to `SQLite` db with in the app. I am unable to extract the data from array and getting the following error

> "at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to
>   JSONArray" on JSONArray arr =object.getJSONArray("response");

I am not well verse with `HttpPost` and would appreciate any detail help I can get. I have tried few things from net but was not successful.

```
Array 
  ( 
     [response] => Array 
       ( 
           [Filepathserver] => webaddress 
           [email] => xyz@email.com
           [syncstatus] => yes 
       ) 

)
```

java file

```
   String url = "uploadphpfile.php";
    File file = new File(filepath);
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

         httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        Log.d("enitity",mpEntity.toString());

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

       String result = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray arr =object.getJSONArray("response");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("filepathserver",obj.get("Filepathserver").toString());
        }
        //Do something with response...
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
          String  responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            String responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                    + statusCode;
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(DBHelperReports.class.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), 
  e);
     }
    }
```

php file

```
   $response = array();
  $response["Filepathserver"] = $target_path;
  $response["email"] = $target_path;
  $response["syncstatus"] = 'yes';
  echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response));
```

Logcat

```
  Value 
 {"Filepathserver":"webaddress","email":"xyz@email.com","syncstatus":"yes"} 
 at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

 org.json.JSONException: Value 
 {"Filepathserver":"webaddress","email":"xyz@email.com","syncstatus":"yes"} 
 at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

 at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)

 at com.multiinspectionelite.DBHelperReports$1.run(DBHelperReports.java:383)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Type mismatch error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your php file produced a json object, not a json array.

so, try `JSONObject arr =object.getJSONObject("response");`

By the way, your logcat had already reminded you to treat it as a JSONObject.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understand it is an Object but how can JSONArray within the JSON Object

Comment: For example:

    {
      "animals": {
        "dogs": [
          {
            "name": "Snoopy",
            "color": "white",
            "age": "1"
          }
        ],
        "cats": [
          {
            "name": "Kitty",
            "color": "white",
            "age": "1"
          },
          {
            "text": "Garfield",
            "color": "orange",
            "age": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

`animals` is a `JSONObject`. It contains two `JSONArray`s.
`cats` and `dogs` are `JSONArray`s. What in `cats` or `dogs` are `JSONObject`s.